# What kind of variables does ARC manage?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Could someone please clarify exactly what ARC manages? Ive heard it does not manage c-structs, but i still see people using them. Please tell me which of the varialbes below will be managed by ARC and why.

```
static CGPoint _var1;
int _var2;

@interface class1:NSObject
    CGPoint _var3;
    CGPoint _var4;
    NSString *_var5;
    NSString *_var6;
}
@property (assign) CGPoint var3;
@property (strong) NSString *var5;
@end

@implentation class1
@synthesize var3 = _var3;
@synthesise var5 = _var5;
@end
```

Comment: Why couldn't types not managed by ARC used? As if you couldn't use `int` anymore because it's not an Objective-C object...

Comment: @H2CO3: Obviosly they can be used, but you need to know which of your variables are being managed because if you manually release something managed by arc u get major errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC manages Objective-C objects automatically.   All other types are managed just as they always have been in C.

Note that in your example, there is no allocation associated with the CGPoint instance variables;   there memory is effectively allocated inline with the object.

Comment: assume that i do assign something to the cgpoints. since they are structs if i dont manually release them will there be a memory leak?

Comment: No. As bbum said, there's no allocation involved in those. They're part of your object's memory. If they were pointers to CGPoints, and you malloc()ed what they pointed to, you would need to free() them.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to MRC (as opposed to GC - which is now deprecated) ARC manages Objective-C objects - no `retain`, `release` or `autorelease`.

In general it does not manage core foundation objects - for those `CFRetain` and `CFRelease` are still required.

ARC does not manage C objects allocated with `malloc` and friends, for those manual memory management is required.

C structures are not dynamically allocated, they are *value types* just like integers and characters. If you declare *pointers* to C structures and dynamically allocate them using `malloc` and friends then you manage those manually as with any other dynamically allocated C object.

What you have have heard about in relation to ARC and C structures is a change to what field types are allowed. Under MRC the declaration:

```
typedef struct
{
   int count;
   NSString *name;
} Item;
```

is *valid* and `name` is managed manually using the usual `retain` etc. However with ARC it is *disallowed*, no object reference managed by ARC may be used as a field type in a structure.

The recommended alternative for the above structure is to use an Obj-C object instead. However if you really need value semantics the field can be marked with the `__unsafe_unretained` attribute:

```
typedef struct
{
   int count;
   __unsafe_unretained NSString *name;
} Item;
```

This attribute instructs ARC to ignore any reference stored into the `name` field for the purposes of determining whether an object should be retained or released. ARC may at any time release an object referenced by `name`, hence *unsafe* & *unretained*. To use such a structure safely you must ensure that the object referenced is kept around by others means, e.g. by having a strong reference to it that ARC is managing.